# PHP Question to Fix WooCommerce Product "Tab" Content Not Displaying that Should (Divi Child Theme)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

If anyone is able to help, I'd be so grateful. Small business owner here and my partner and I just have to figure this stuff ourselves right now. I am on Woocommerce- Divi Child Theme.

I want to override WooCommerce's default "tab" order (the menu bar under product pics that says "Description", Additional Info" and "Reviews")

I already added my own tab for "Recipes" and I need that to show first (already be loaded on the page without having to click the tab. After some Googling, adding this code in the functions.php file helped me get the "Recipes" tab to show first and display all the content without having to click on it:

```
/**
* Reorder product data tabs
*/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_reorder_tabs', 98 );
function woo_reorder_tabs( $tabs ) {
    $tabs['recipes']['priority']                = 5; // Recipes first
    $tabs['description']['priority']            = 10; // Description second
    $tabs['reviews']['priority']                = 15; // Reviews third
    $tabs['additional_information']['priority'] = 20; // Additional information fourth
    return $tabs;
}
```

BUT now the issue is I have many product pages that will never have/need a "recipes" tab. So in those cases it just shows "Description", Additional Info" and "Reviews" however it hides the content under "Description now. And I need that content to automatically show. Any idea how I can fix this or is there something in the above CSS telling it to hide it unless clicked?

UPDATE ~~~~~~~~~
Here is a screenshot of the code from the plugin (it won't let me add the image since I'm new, but I think the iage link should work):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bepgo.png)

UPDATE: Here's actual live pages showing the issue: Here's a spice blend page where its displaying as we want (showing recipes as the first tab under the product pics): https://pinchspicemarket.com/product/buffys-slayer-helper/

and this is an example of a "basic spice" page where we don't have recipes/likely won't ever and we want the description tab to show instead with the full content displayed (but you have to click on it to view that content now): https://pinchspicemarket.com/product/cinnamon-powder-ceylon/

Comment: There should be some additional code that is adding the recipes tab to start with. Can you include that or is it a plugin that is doing it?

Comment: Thank you so much Mark! Yes we use a plugin called to add a custom "recipes" tab. It's called Custom Product Tabs for WooCommerce Version 1.7.7 | By YIKES, Inc. I will post the code below if that's helpful (it appears there's a character limit for comments here so it may have to be split in two comments).

Comment: | <ul class="tabs wc-tabs" role="tablist">
       <li class="recipes_tab active" id="tab-title-recipes" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-recipes">
     <a href="#tab-recipes">
      Recipes     </a>
    </li>
       <li class="description_tab" id="tab-title-description" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-description">
     <a href="#tab-description">
      Description     </a>
    </li>

Comment: <li class="additional_information_tab" id="tab-title-additional_information" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-additional_information">
     <a href="#tab-additional_information">
      Additional information     </a>
    </li>
       <li class="reviews_tab" id="tab-title-reviews" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-reviews">
     <a href="#tab-reviews">
      Reviews (1)     </a>
    </li>
     </ul>

Comment: Please add that to your question vs comments. It makes it easier for anyone to read.

Comment: Sorry, new here. Will do

Comment: Are you able to link to the page? it would be easier to see what is getting returned.

Comment: Yes thank so much. Will link here in comments and update in the post.  Here's a spice blend page where its displaying as we want (showing recipes as the first tab under the product pics): https://pinchspicemarket.com/product/buffys-slayer-helper/ and this is an example of a "basic spice" page where we don't have recipes/likely won't ever and we want the description tab to show instead with the full content displayed (but you have to click on it to view that content now): https://pinchspicemarket.com/product/cinnamon-powder-ceylon/

Answer (score 0):

So I did an install of that plugin and it looks like all you need to do is remove the Tab on the products you don't want it on.

[image]

They are assuming if you have a custom tab on a product that you intend to use it so don't bother to do a check if the content is empty.

Comment: I see that "remove tab" only on the pages that already have the custom "recipes" tab. When I go to pages w/out a recipes tab (like the Ceylon cinnamon), there's no option to remove it because there is not one there.

Comment: I upgraded to pro & don't see an option to display description content when "description" is the first tab (when there is no recipes tab). I may need to delete the old custom recipes tabs and create new ones by giving the rule to only apply it to the product category I want. It stinks because I had to manually add links to all the blog recipes but if it takes a few days to get it right, I'll do it (unless you have any ideas?). Thank you again for your time. You are very generous.

Comment: Ahh Pro allows you to globally add the tab? I would think you can just adjust that setting vs having to redo it all. As well, you could create a backup and try removing it/re-adding it. Its very possible it doesn't delete the data and may match it back up.

Comment: Ok, I feel like an idiot. I just asked myself why do I still have that CSS in my functions/php file if I upgraded and now can use the plugin to reorder the recipes to the front (when there is a recipe tab already created)? So I used the tool to say "put the recipes tab first" and deleted that CSS code. Now everything is working! One the pages that have recipes, that tab shows first now. And on the ones that don't, the description content shows too. All for just $30 to buy the dang plugin! Doh, I shoulda thought of this earlier.

Comment: Thats interesting. I'll have to test that with the plugin/custom order. Seems weird it was just putting a tab without content first that didn't exist.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Mark!

Comment: You're welcome even though you figured out the answer to your own question!

Comment: Yes, the pro version lets you add a tab globally if you want, or you can add a tab based on things like categories or product tags. Totally worth the $29.99 imo :) It was pulling that tab because of that code I put in the functions.php file - that conflicted with the plugin I think. After switching to pro I still had the same issue, but then I just deleted that extra code I added in the functions.php file and the issue went away.